# Problem retrieving image in scoped storage Android 11

Tags: android, image, cordova, storage, sandbox

I'm using Anoidroid 11 and I'm retriving image from my app scoped storage.
I always get imaget not found. What's wrong?

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function success(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile(value, { create: false, exclusive: false }, 
        function fileExist(fileEntry){
            element.attr('src', fileEntry.toURL());
        }, 
        function fileDoesNotExist(){
            alert('Image not found' + value);
        });
    }, 
    function fail(evt) {
        alert('error: ' + evt.target.error.code);
    }
);
```

Value is the name of the image file in the sandbox storage area.
Thanks

Comment: Full path please. Who put that image there?

Comment: I'm converting/saving a base64 image string to the gallery using plugin https://github.com/Heartade/cordova-plugin-android-mediastore . Already tried with "cordova.file.externalDataDirectory", "cordova.file.dataDirectory" and "cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory". Should I use resolveLocalFileSystemURL or requestFileSystem ? (I'm using Android 11)

Comment: After saving you should know where your image is stored. Find out first. You did not tell any full path yet. Find out full path of all mentioned functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's camera doesnot have permission to write in the specified location. So to fix this, you need to use file provider and give it appropriate permissions so that the camera can write the image to your file.

To do that,

1. create a FileProvider. In your manifest file, add:

   ```
   <provider
       android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />        // <-------- see this
   </provider>
   ```

Now create a files.xml file in your res/xml folder. In it, write some code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<cache-path
    name="camera"
    path="Camera/" />
<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="/" />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
<external-files-path
    name="my_images"
    path="/"/>

  // todo: add necessary folders according to your requirements...
  // also, this is an old example. Consider googling for the latest style. 
  // I'm just copying from an old project I have, and it kinda works...
 </paths>
```

So here we are giving the FileProvider the folders that can be shared with external apps. 2. Now create a uri where you want to store the photo. in your activity:

```
Context applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
File root = getCachedDir(); // consider using 
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 
// you need to check the file_paths.xml
    File capturedPhoto = new File(root, "some_photo.jpeg");
    if(!photoFile.exists()) {
        photoFile.mkdirs();
    }
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, applicationContext.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", capturedPhoto);
```

Please note that my project needed to save picture temporarily, so I had used cachedDir. If you save photo permanently, use getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); and modify file_paths.xml properly.

Now that we have the correct uri, we can call the camera intent:

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Finally, in activity result, do something:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
      // todo: maybe show photo in an imageView
    }
}
```